# Visual Studio Code Python refuses to write to file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, file-io

I'm trying to have a program output data to a JSON file, but VS code or Python itself seems to have a problem with that. Specifically, I'm trying to output this(Tlist and Slist are lists of integers):

```
output = {"Time": Tlist, "Space": Slist}
json_data = json.dumps(output, indent=4)
with open("sortsOutput.json", "a") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_data)
```

But nothing seems to be happening. SortsOutput.json was never made, and even with a pre-existing SortsOuput.json nothing happened. Heck, this doesn't even work:

```
out = open("blah.txt", "w")
out.write("Egg")
out.close()
```

What might be going wrong for my software for this to happen? I'm using Python v2022.16.1, for the record, and every time the program runs for the first time the command "conda activate base" happens with some error text that doesn't seem to affect the rest of my program, so is it that? How do I fix that?

Comment: Your Python "version" doesn't make sense. You might want to check that. Remember also that the sortsOutput.json will be created in the same directory where your Python script resides. You may be looking for it in the wrong place

Comment: "Heck, this doesn't even work:" Why do you think it isn't working? In particular: **where** do you think the written file should be? **Why** do you think it should be there?

Comment: (As an aside, the JSON data format will not work properly with appending. A JSON file is supposed to describe a **single** JSON array or object.)

Answer (score 0):

> out = file.open("blah.txt", "w")

In your second example, it seems that you don't need `file.`. `open()` is a built-in method of Python.
You can use `out = open("blah.txt", "w")` directly.

At the same time, this problem seems to have nothing to do with vscode.

I think this problem is more likely due to the path problem. The `.json` file you executed does not exist in the first level directory under the workspace.

For example,

```
Workspace
 -.vscode
  -sortsOutput.json
 -test.py
```

You need to use the workspace as the root directory to tell the specific location of python files:

```
with open(".vscode/sortsOutput.json", "a") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to write file using MS Visual Studio Community (python), in my case it was an encoding issue. I found the solution at: https://peps.python.org/pep-0263/ just put a special comment: `# coding=<encoding name>` at the first line of the python script

(in my case: # coding=utf-8)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).